# Applying animation to an activity when an activity is ending?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I have two activities A and B.I am trying to implement animations to activity when navigating.This is how it should work.

When a Fling bottom-to-top happens in A > A ends sliding-up and B enters from Bottom sliding-in.When a Fling top-to-bottom happens in B,B ends sliding-down and A enters sliding-in from top.

I implemented both the enter transitions using `overridePendingTransition(enter, stops);` for both the activity. But i am not possible to give the animation when an acitivity is ending.I tried using `overridePendingTransition(enter, stops);` inside `onStop` and `OnPause` it working when I press the hardware back button but its not working when I navigate through the activities using fling and this confuses me.

Can anyone help me to tackle this problem.???

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29)  overridePendingTransition (int enterAnim, int exitAnim) should be called just after finish() or startActivity().

It do not need to be called in onStop() or onPause().

Comment: Ya I tried that but the activity is not showing animation when its ending.

Comment: on fling you navigating through startActivity()? can you post your code

Comment: YOU NEED MORE UPVOTES!